# Snowflake Error: network config is not found

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are getting error on running below
system$GET_SNOWFLAKE_PLATFORM_INFO()

Error "**network config  is not found Please contact support**"

Network Policies are already set.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks,

Comment: Hi - what role are you using when you run this?

Comment: Hi Nick , accountadmin

Comment: In which case I would suggest following the course of action that the error message suggests

Comment: :) Yes we opened SF case. Thanks Nick

Comment: This should be now fixed.